# Deriving data from a history table

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database that manages a library of dog toys.

The `dog_toy_history` table keeps track of which toys a dog has checked out from
the toy library.  A dog can only have a new toy when a toy is returned, 
a dog can only have one toy at a time.

```
CREATE TABLE `dog_toy_history` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dog_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `toy_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `dog_toy_history`
  (`id`,`dog_id`,`toy_id`,`created_date`) 
VALUES  
  (1,1,'a','2013-07-05 00:00:00'),
  (2,2,'b','2013-07-15 00:00:00'),
  (3,3,'c','2013-07-20 00:00:00'),
  (4,1,'d','2013-07-25 00:00:00'),
  (5,2,'a','2013-08-05 00:00:00'),
  (6,1,'b','2013-08-10 00:00:00'),
  (7,2,'d','2013-08-15 00:00:00'),
  (8,1,'a','2013-08-20 00:00:00');
```

Given a dog_id, and a date range, I want to be able to determine the toys the
dog had during that range, and the dates they had the toy from and to.

### Example Query 1

```
set @dog_id = 1;
set @start_date = '2013-07-05';
set @end_date = '2013-07-25';

<run special query> ... desired result:

    toy_id, start_date, end_date
    a       2013-07-05  2013-07-25
    d       2013-07-25  2013-07-25
```

### Example Query 2

```
set @dog_id = 1;
set @start_date = '2013-07-05';
set @end_date = '2013-08-19';

<run special query> ... desired result:

    toy_id, start_date, end_date
    a       2013-07-05  2013-07-25
    d       2013-07-25  2013-08-10
    b       2013-08-10  2013-08-19
```

### Example Query 2

```
set @dog_id = 2;
set @start_date = '2013-07-01';
set @end_date = '2013-09-01';

<run special query> ... desired result:

    toy_id, start_date, end_date
    b       2013-07-15  2013-08-05
    a       2013-08-05  2013-08-15
    d       2013-08-15  2013-09-01
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work for you. I tested in my local mysql database with the data you provided and it worked.

```
select dth.toy_id, dth.created_date as start_date, 
       ifnull((select min(dth2.created_date) from dog_toy_history dth2 where dth2.created_date > dth.created_date and dth2.dog_id='2'),'2013-09-01') as end_date 
       from dog_toy_history dth
       where (dth.created_date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-09-01') and dog_id='2' ORDER by start_date;
```

I will give some explanation for those who are not very familiar with mysql:

- the inner select brings the **created_date** field of the next toy if existent. This will represent the **end_date** of the current toy.
- `ifnull(exp1,exp2)` specifies a default if a next toy is inexistent. In this case the **end_date** will be the end date from the input.